# matlab adding to a vector

Tags: matlab, vector

```
 clear all
    data = rand(8760,1);
    n=366;
    time=linspace(1+1/24,n,(n-1)*24)';
        %day of year
    daylims = ([100,300]);

    [row1]=find(time > daylims(1) & time < daylims(2));
```

From the example above I'm trying to select the data for e period given by 'daylims' and then fit that data into a vector which corresponds to 'time'. Having found the row number for the data which I need, all I'm trying to do now is to surround the 'data' with nans e.g. first row is 2377 so then I want to make row 1:2377 as nan and as the last row is 7175 so I want to make 
row 7175:end as nan (end is 8760).

This can easily be done by moving the values around manually but I was hoping of a more 
efficient method. Let me know if I'm not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often do it like this:

```
good_data = (time > daylims(1) & time < daylims(2)); 
data(~good_data)=NaN;
```

Note I do not use find but logical indexing instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this approach?

```
data(1 : 2377) = nan;
data(7175 : end) = nan;
```

Comment: yes I did this, but I was looking for a more sophisticated approach. If I would need to do this for a larger dataset, then it would be very time consuming.